# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers') with next.js new app router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Updated code after some suggestions from comments (still getting the same error):

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")
const User = require("../../model/userModel")

export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  await dbConnect()
  const res = await req.json()
  await bcrypt.hash(res.passwd, 10)
      .then(async (hashedPassword: any) => {
          //create a new user instance and collect the data
          const user = new User({
              firstname: res.firstname,
              lastname: res.lastname,
              company: res.company,
              phone: res.phone,
              email: res.email,
              password: hashedPassword,
          })
          await user.save()
          //return succes if the new user is added to the database
          .then((result: string) => {
              return NextResponse.json({message: "User created successfully "},{status : 201}) 
          })
          .catch((err: string) => {
            console.log("error" + err)
            return NextResponse.json({message: "Error creating user :"},{status : 500}) 
          })
      })
      .catch((err: string) => {
        console.log("error" + err)
        return NextResponse.json({message: "Password was not hashed successfully "},{status : 500})  
      })
}
```

I can't find out why I get this error:

```
  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers')
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:265:61)    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

I've seen a similar error, but the answer to that problem was to return the `NextResponse.json()`. I'm already doing it but I still get the error.

This is where I'm calling the POST request:

```
async function createUser(ev: any){
        ev.preventDefault()
        const data = {firstname, lastname, company, phone, email, passwd}
        await axios.post("./api/register", data)
    }

    //Email validation
    function isValidEmail(email: string) {
        return /\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(email);
      }
      

  return (
    <>
        <main className="flex justify-center items-center w-screen min-h-screen bg-[url('../public/bg-login.jpg')] bg-no-repeat bg-cover">
            <div className="flex flex-col w-1/2 h-3/4 rounded-lg shadow-2xl shadow-white m-5">
                <form onSubmit={createUser} className="w-full"> 
                    <div className="grid sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 gap-10 mb-5 mr-5 ml-5 mt-5">
                        <div>
                            <label htmlFor="firstname" className="text-white block mb-2 text-sm font-medium dark:text-white">*First name</label>
                            <input 
                                className="outline-none bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:border-blue-500 p-2 w-full" 
                                type="text"
                                onChange={ (e) => {
                                setFirstname(e.target.value)
                                }}
                                placeholder="First name"
                                value={firstname} 
                                id="firstname"
                                required/>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label htmlFor="lastname" className="text-white block mb-2 text-sm font-medium dark:text-white">*Last name</label>
                            <input 
                                className="outline-none bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:border-blue-500 p-2 w-full" 
                                type="text"
                                onChange={ (e) => {
                                setLastname(e.target.value)
                                }}
                                placeholder="Last name"
                                value={lastname} 
                                id="lastname"
                                required/>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label htmlFor="company" className="text-white block mb-2 text-sm font-medium dark:text-white">*Company</label>
                            <input 
                                className="outline-none bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:border-blue-500 p-2 w-full" 
                                type="text"
                                onChange={ (e) => {
                                setCompany(e.target.value)
                                }}
                                placeholder="Zincometal"
                                value={company} 
                                id="company"
                                required/>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label htmlFor="phone" className="text-white block mb-2 text-sm font-medium dark:text-white">*Phone number</label>
                            <input 
                                className="outline-none bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:border-blue-500 p-2 w-full" 
                                type="number"
                                onChange={ (e) => 
                                    {  
                                        setPhone(e.target.valueAsNumber)       
                                    }}
                                placeholder="xx-xxx-xxx-xx"
                                value={phone} 
                                id="phone"
                                required/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="md:col-span-2 sm:col-span-1">
                            <label htmlFor="email" className="text-white block mb-2 text-sm font-medium dark:text-white">*Email Address</label>
                            <input 
                                className="outline-none bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:border-blue-500 p-2 w-full" 
                                type="text"
                                onChange={ (e) => 
                                    {  
                                        if (!isValidEmail(e.target.value)){
                                            setError(true)
                                        }else{
                                            setError(false)
                                        }
                                        setEmail(e.target.value)       
                                    }}
                                placeholder="example@hotmail.com"
                                value={email} 
                                id="email"
                                required/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="md:col-span-2 sm:col-span-1">
                            <label htmlFor="passwd" className="text-white block mb-2 text-sm font-medium dark:text-white">*Password</label>
                            <input 
                                className="outline-none bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:border-blue-500 p-2 w-full" 
                                type="password"
                                onChange={ (e) => 
                                    {  
                                            setPasswd(e.target.value)       
                                    }}
                                placeholder="*******"
                                value={passwd} 
                                id="passwd"
                                required/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="md:col-span-2 sm:col-span-1">
                            <label htmlFor="confPasswd" className="text-white block mb-2 text-sm font-medium dark:text-white">*Confirm Password</label>
                            <input 
                                className="outline-none bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:border-blue-500 p-2 w-full" 
                                type="password"
                                onChange={ (e) => 
                                    {  
                                            setConfPasswd(e.target.value)       
                                    }}
                                placeholder="*******"
                                value={confPasswd} 
                                id="confPasswd"
                                required/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="flex items-start">
                            <div className="flex items-center h-6">
                                <input
                                    className="w-4 h-4 border border-gray-300 rounded bg-gray-50 focus:ring-3 focus:ring-blue-300" 
                                    type="checkbox" 
                                    value='' 
                                    id="remember"/>
                            </div>
                            <label htmlFor="remember" className="ml-2 text-sm font-medium text-white">
                                I agree with the <a href="#" className="text-blue-600 hover:underline dark:text-blue-500">terms and conditions</a>.
                            </label>
                            <Link href="./" className="mr-5 mt-5 font-medium text-white text-right hover:underline decoration-solid">
                                Return to login &lt;--
                            </Link>
                            {error && <div>{error}</div>}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" className="ml-5 mb-5 text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm w-full sm:w-auto px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </main>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you try awaiting `bcrypt.hash` and `user.save` and return the response.

Comment: I think you are doing invalid json. It should be `return NextResponse.json({message: "User created successfully", status: 201})`

Comment: Im still getting the same error  tried both of your solutions@CodeThing

Comment: Try changing the return for error scenarios as well. you are passing multiple objects there.

Comment: I tried it while I was changing the ```return NextResponse.json({message: "User created successfully", status: 201})``` still getting the same error

Comment: What is the value of `result` inside `then()` after saving the user?

Comment: use server side debugger to identify the cause.

Comment: @GabrielLupu after saving the user my code never goes to the then() it goes to catch() and i cant find why

update:And I fund out why somehow I messed up the firstname as my model schema has username and not firstname

Comment: this is the result value inside then() : 

`{
  firstname: 'test',
  lastname: 'test',
  company: 'test',
  phone: 234234,
  email: 'test@test.com',
  password: '$2b$10$Vlbb1nsERd4KPqMrgEyxW.CwiD1nFfEn1tNd53Aa4ZKQQqkdxo716',
  date: 2023-07-21T07:27:02.944Z,
  _id: new ObjectId("64ba3481a6e29a160ea75f09"),
  __v: 0
}` 
The user get's added the the database but i still get the error
@GabrielLupu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have some wrongly formatted JSON in your `NextResponse`
I would check each one if it's valid by console logging with `JSON.stringify(responseThatIWantToSend)` before returning with `NextResponse`.
Also, for clarity I would only use the `async...await` with `try...catch` syntax.

```js
// specific name for the function
export async function createUser(req: NextRequest) {
  try {
    await dbConnect()
    const res = await req.json()
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(res.passwd, 10)
    const user = new User({
      firstname: res.firstname,
      lastname: res.lastname,
      company: res.company,
      phone: res.phone,
      email: res.email,
      password: hashedPassword,
    })

    await user.save();
    // Try first sending back simple reponses to see if it works
    // if it does, add status and user props to your response
    return NextResponse.json({
      message: 'User saved'
    })
  } catch (error) {
    // degug error
    console.log('error', error);
    return NextResponse.json(error, {
      status: 500
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: `1.return NextResponse.json({message: "User created successfully "},{status : 201})
2.return NextResponse.json({message: "Error creating user "},{status : 500}) 
3.return NextResponse.json({message: "Password was not hashed successfully "},{status : 500}) ` 

after a comment I got I changed that to this ^ but im still getting the same error.Il try to console log it to check if something is wrong

Comment: Try using my code, see if it works. Or if anything changes.

Comment: Please add some code about where the function to create the user is being invoked.

Comment: I updated my question you can check the code which calls the function

Comment: I guess the problem was here 
`await user.save()
       .then((result: string) => {
             return NextResponse.json({message: "User created successfully "},{status :201}) 
          })
          .catch((err: string) => {
            console.log("error" + err)
            return NextResponse.json({message: "Error creating user :"},{status : 500}) 
          })`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem, and after some investigation, I managed to resolve it by adding the line
`return NextResponse.json(store);`
inside the try block. I thought I'd share my solution here in case it helps others facing the same issue.

Initially, I was experiencing [describe your initial problem briefly]. After reviewing the code, I noticed that the try-catch block was not handling the response correctly, which caused the problem. So, I decided to add the following line inside the try block just before the catch block:

```
return NextResponse.json(store);
```

This line specifically handles the response and ensures that the data is correctly returned from the API call. After making this change, the issue was resolved, and everything worked as expected.

Keep in mind that the specific solution might vary depending on your code and the context of your problem, but for me, this addition proved to be the fix. Remember to also check if there are any other potential issues in your code that could be causing the problem.

I hope this solution helps others facing a similar problem. If you have any questions or need further assistance, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in your then block formatted wrong with the curly brackets. Which is causing that weird error. I believe your original implementation should work.

```
then(async (hashedPassword: any) => { <= remove
          //create a new user instance and collect the data
          const user = new User({
              firstname: res.firstname,
              lastname: res.lastname,
              company: res.company,
              phone: res.phone,
              email: res.email,
              password: hashedPassword,
          })
          await user.save()
          //return succes if the new user is added to the database
          .then((result: string) => {
              return NextResponse.json({message: "User created successfully "},{status : 201}) 
          })
          .catch((err: string) => {
            console.log("error" + err)
            return NextResponse.json({message: "Error creating user :"},{status : 500}) 
          })
     => remove })
```

You can also reference my implementation

```
export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const request = await req.json();
    const { name, email, password } = request;
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (user) {
      throw new Error("User already exist!");
    }

    return bcrypt.hash(password, 10).then((hash: any) =>
      User.create({ name, email, password: hash }).then((user: any) => {
        return NextResponse.json({ message: "User saved" });
      })
    );
  } catch (error: any) {
    NextResponse.json({ message: error.message, status: 500 });
  }
}
```

Comment: @Thodoris_Diamantidis

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).